# Go: go doc, go test

Tags: golang, консоль

Изучаю го, прохожу создание документации. Написал пару комментариев в программе и написал в терминале команду

```sh
$ go doc "[путь к файлу от названия проекта до папки файла]"
```

Выводит это:

```
doc: no buildable Go source files in C:\Users\korzh\Programming\GoProjects\src\study
exit status 1
```

После чего попробовал ввести "go test" и получаю тоже ошибку:

```
?       study/pointer   [no test files]
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

У вас две несвязные проблемы. Во-первых, «go doc» прежде всего рассчитан на работу с конкретными идентификаторами. Например:

```sh
$ go doc encoding/json.SyntaxError

type SyntaxError struct {
    Offset int64 // error occurred after reading Offset bytes
    // Has unexported fields.
}
    A SyntaxError is a description of a JSON syntax error.

func (e *SyntaxError) Error() string
```

Во-вторых, чтобы работал «go test» нужно добавить тестовые файлы в ваш проект. Например, чтобы протестировать сущности из файла «foo.go», надо создать файл «foo_test.go».

Answer (score 0):

**1)** go test не работает из-за отсутствия тестовых файлов.

**2)** go doc [-u] [-c] [package|[package.]symbol[.methodOrField]] - для go doc нужен идентификатор. Рекомендую ознакомиться [здесь](https://russianblogs.com/article/22441280811/)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)